# Why compactness is named 'compactness'?

Tags: terminology, compactness

There are many nice discussions here (see [disussion1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371928/what-should-be-the-intuition-when-working-with-compactness),[discussion2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485822/why-is-compactness-so-important),[discussion3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/how-to-understand-compactness)) to show compactness is kind of 'finiteness', which means some properties of finite set can then be used for infinite set, in the way of local-to-global principles. Or, as said "finiteness =  compactness + discreteness".

My question is: why we use word "compact" to describe this property? By literal meaning, compact means tightly packed. So, is there anything really ***compact*** when we have the property of compactness ?

Comment: Well, a compact disc is certainly compact. Maybe not as much as a minidisc, but certainly compared to a vinyl record.

Comment: The term was introduced by Maurice Frechet in 1904, at least according to Wikipedia. Perhaps someone who can read French can shed some light on the reasons for the terminology, if such were given.

Comment: I dont know if it is the historic origin, but @JoséCarlosSantos do give an acceptable explanation. @ AsafKaragila

Comment: That is good, XLiu, that you found an acceptable answer.  Hold off on accepting it if you hope that others may also post an answer in an effort to explain it differently.  (As a rule, once you accept an answer, the chances of getting any additional explanations plummets.)  So no need to rush to accept the first answer you receive, unless/until others also post answers, and you still prefer the first one.

Comment: Definitely. Hope there are many more interesting answers.@amWhy

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In a compact space, every infinite set has a limit point. Therefore, infinite subsets of compact spaces cannot be spread, in the sense that each point is far from the other ones.

Comment: this make sense. Thank you.